# Javascript regexp replace of multiline content between two tags (including the tags)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In the string

```
some text <p id='item_1' class='item'>multiline content\r\n\r\n for <br/>remove</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_1'/><p id='item_2' class='item'>another multiline content\r\n\r\n</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_2'/>
```

I need to remove

```
<p id='item_1' class='item'>multiline content\r\n\r\n for <br/>remove</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_1'/>
```

Can't find a way how to do it.

```
var id = 'item_1';
var patt=new RegExp("<p id='"+id+"'(.)*|([\S\s]*?)end_of_"+id+"'\/>","g");
var str="some text <p id='item_1' class='item'>multiline content\r\n\r\n for <br/>remove</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_1'/><p id='item_2' class='item'>another multiline content\r\n\r\n</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_2'/>";
document.write(str.replace(patt,""));
```

The result is

```
some text for
<br>
remove
<p></p>
<br id="<p id=" class="item" clear="all" item_2'="">
another multiline content
<p></p>
<br id="end_of_item_2" clear="all">
```

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Regular expressions to parse HTML is a bad practice. If you want you can pass the string to a library like jQuery, remove appropriate elements and get it back as a string.

Comment: In the real example string contains unclosed tags (this is part of the template). That's why I can't parse it and use DOM API for removing.

Comment: @mihserf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the regex for the current scenario.  When the regex approach eventually breaks, remember that we warned that parsing HTML with regex was a fool's errand. ;)

This:

```
var s        = "some text <p id='item_1' class='item'>multiline content\r\n\r\n for <br/>remove</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_1'/><p id='item_2' class='item'>another multiline content\r\n\r\n</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_2'/><ul><li>";
var id       = 'item_1';

var patt     = new RegExp ("<p[^<>]*\\sid=['\"]" + id + "['\"](?:.|\\n|\\r)*<br[^<>]*\\sid=['\"]end_of_" + id + "['\"][^<>]*>", "ig")

var stripped = s.replace (patt, "");
```

Produces this:

```
"some text <p id='item_2' class='item'>another multiline content 

</p><br clear='all' id='end_of_item_2'/><ul><li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the DOM API to remove it? (add everything to the document, and then remove what you don't need)

```
var item1 = document.getElementById('item_1'),
    endOfItem1 = document.getElementById('end_of_item_1');

item1.parentNode.removeChild(item1);
endOfItem1.parentNode.removeChild(endOfItem1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't use DOM because this is value of the textarea and it includes unclosed tags too. So this should be solved only by regexp

Answer (score 0):

I need to assume a bit of unspoken constraints from your question, to get this to work:

Am I right in guessing, that you want a regex, that can find (and then replace) any 'p' tag with a specific id, up to a certain tag (like e.g. a 'br' tag) with an id of 'end_of_[firstid]'?

If that is correct, than the following regex might work for you. It may be, that you need to modify it a bit, to get JS to accept it:

```
<p\s+id='([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'.*?id='end_of_\1'\s*\/>
```

This will give you any constellation with the criteria, describled above, and the name if the id as group 1, It should now be a simple task, to check if group1 contains the id you want to remove and then replace the whole match with an empty string.

If I understand your example correcty (I am not that good with JavaScript and my RegEx was based rather on the general perl-regex fashion) you could maybe do something like the following:

```
var patt=new RegExp("<p\s+id='"+id+"'.*?id='end_of_"+id+"'\s*\/>","g");
```

That way, you don't have to worry about group matching, although I find it to be more elegant, to match the id you wanted via a group instead of inserting it into the RegEx.

Comment: Thanks. You understood my question right. But this regexp doesn't work for my example. I've even removed \r\n\r\n from the string.

Comment: See my edit above. - If that still doesn't do the trick, it might be helpfull, if you try to describle, WHY it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your time. But that regexp doesn't match any from the string in my example... I didn't know why.
Brock Adams provided working regexp.